# wpf как клонировать изображение и переместить

Tags: c#, wpf, imageview

У меня есть несколько изображений на окне. Мне нужно выбрать изображение и перетащить зажав левую кнопку мышки, при этом изображение должно дублироваться, то есть я могу с этого места перетащить несколько таких изображений.

Я много вариантов перепробовал с интернета, но ни один не работает

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Берем ItemsControl, ставим Canvas ему как панель, берем коллекцию типа ObservableCollection, например из классов с координатами и ссылками на картинки (у вас же есть модель данных?), привязываем ItemsControl к коллекции, засовываем элемент в Adorner, добавляем Thumb и за него таскаем мышью. Чтобы изображение дублировалось, надо просто в коллекции создать его копию перед перетаскиванием. Это ведь вы тоже пробовали?